# Parse a long string with a pattern

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I would appreciate some assistance in a tricky task I have to complete.

I receive a long long string in a text file  which look like this :

```
{"place":"1","points":"1783","pseudo":"player1"},
{"place":"2","points":"1675","pseudo":"player34"},
{"place":"3","points":"1671","pseudo":"player45"},
```

So this is a single string with about 3000 times the same pattern stuck together. (there are 3000 players)

I would need to parse this string to fill a  simple structure like this

```
public struct RankedPlayer
{
    public string Pseudo;
    public int Place;
    public int Point;
}
```

I don't find a easy way to do this. I start to struggle with RegEx but I don't know if it's a right approach.

Comment: It's a JSON. Use [**Json.NET**](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to parse it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're dealing with a simple JSON string.
Use JSON parson [james.newtonking.com - json](http://james.newtonking.com/json), and simply get them as your object ...

Here's an example:

```
// Having this:
public struct RankedPlayer
{
   public string Pseudo;
   public int Place;
   public int Point;
}

// With this input
{"place":"1","points":"1783","pseudo":"player1"},
{"place":"2","points":"1675","pseudo":"player34"},
{"place":"3","points":"1671","pseudo":"player45"},

// You should do something like:
string input = // your input;
var list_of_players = input.Split(',');

foreach (var player in list_of_players) {
    RankedPlayer r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RankedPlayer>(player);
    // Do something with it.
}
```

So, just use your `Player` structure.

**Edit:**

You can use the following for your regex: `{.*?}` matching. Basically match everything between the curly braces, in a non greedy way (the `?` after the `.*`).

Comment: I think it's necessary to add attributes to the structure fields because of name mismatches.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't know about JSON string !  However there are commas everywhere in the string .  If I do : "var list_of_players = input.Split(',');", I won't get a real list of player's substrings.

Comment: @Fyodor He might need to do that, true. Or he can do it manually if he prefers.

Comment: @flamandier I'm not sure if Newtonsoft can deserialize into a list of objects, I'll have a look a bit later, but if that's the case,  you can split on `},` and then just append the `{` to each string inside the foreach... The other option would be to Use a Regex

Comment: @Noctis Also, yes, Newtonsoft can serialize directly into collection, no regex needed.

Comment: @Fyodor Then problem solved even easier than he thought. Not in front of my dev machine, so couldn't give it a test :). You saved me looking at it later for a follow up :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScriptSerializer try:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<RankedPlayer> myData = serializer.Deserialize<List<RankedPlayer>>(strData);
```